# How to traverse/iterate through a nested JAXB object to display it in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, soap, jaxb, unmarshalling

I constructed a soap request and received the response. I unmarshalled the response using JAXB context and got the object which contains the response.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseMessage.class);
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
ResponseMessage output = (NumberResponseMessage)um.unmarshal(soapResponse.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
```

Now I can access the data in the response object (output) via get..()/..getValue() methods and print it in the console. But the issue arises when I try to send the response object by adding it to a ModelAndView attribute to a JSP page.

```
Model model.addAttribute("response", output);
```

The error I get is - JSP don't know how to iterate over the given items(as I try  loop).

```
<c:forEach var ="Res" items="${output}">
<td>${Res.TransactionId}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Since the response object contains hundreds of data and also inner JAXB<> arrays, its not possible to set all the data to a user bean and then access.

Can anyone advice me as how to iterate over the response object in the JSP page?

Comment: Please show us the code you have

Comment: show us the code you have so far

Comment: using a loop to verify whether the input contains one of the specified spacial characters

Comment: or regex, though that would be another problem

Comment: I think you cant write char password[length]; no variable in array subscript.

Comment: This method will mark any password as invalid, as it requires _every_ letter to be lowercase, uppercase and a digit.

Comment: then should i use string(password);

Comment: Why 4 for loops one is more than enough ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better maintain a table for all fair special characters; then you can verify letters that not other types. I suppose you are a new guy on C++; hence an example is what you need.Do as below:

```
bool IsSpecialCharacter(char c)
{
  static special_chars[] = "~`!@#$%^&*()_+-=\\\/?><,.";
  char *p = &special_chars[0];
  while(*p) { 
   if(*p == c) return true;
  };
  return false;
}
```

I though this is what keelar was suggested.

Comment: +1 for a modular approach!  Still, a `++p` somewhere would help ;-). Or, just `return *strchr(special_chars, c);`. Also probably useful to illustrate how to use this per-character checking to validate the entire string, e.g. with `std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), IsSpecialCharacter)` or C++11's `std::any_of`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the code example in the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/).

It uses `std::string::find_first_not_of` and the example actually shows what you want to do! (How cool is that?)

Coping example code from link as suggested by @jogojapan

```
// string::find_first_not_of
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <cstddef>        // std::size_t

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("look for non-alphabetic characters...");

  std::size_t found = str.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ");

  if (found!=std::string::npos)
  {
    std::cout << "The first non-alphabetic character is " << str[found];
    std::cout << " at position " << found << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good and practical approach, and fully C++. I'd suggest copying the example code here (and keeping the link only as a reference), simply because links are not reliable in the long term (even links to cplusplus.com).

Answer (score 1):

you can write a regex in order to find if one character is special or not. Here is example:

```
std::regex rx("[\\[]+|[\"]+|..."); // ... is your special characters
```

create each pattern differently(upper case, lower case, special char) and use

`std::regex_match` which basically returns true if pattern matches whole or part of string.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a `string` of special characters.

```
//some pseudo code
string password = inputedPassword;
string specialChars = "@#$%&*";

for(int i = 0; i < password.length; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < specialChars.length; i++)
      if(password[i] == specialChars[j])
          return true; //there is a special char

 return false; //no special chars
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by your logic this should work fine for you

```
    bool islower= false;
    bool isNumber= false;
    bool isUpper= false;
    bool isSpecialChar=false;


        for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
        {
            if(!islower(password[count])){

                 islower=true;
                 break;
               }
        }

    if(islower){
          for(int count = 0; count < length; count++)
              {
                if( isdigit(password[count])){
                    isNumber=true;
                    break;
                  }
              }

    }

    if(isNumber){
        for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
        {
            if(isupper(password[count])){
               isUpper=true;
               break;
              }
        }

    } 


if(isUpper){
  static special_chars[] = "~`!@#$%^&*()_+-=\\\/?><,.";
  char *p = &special_chars[0];
  for (int count = 0; count < length; count++){
      for(int j=0;j<24;j++){
          if(p[j]==password[count]{
          isSpecialChar=true;
          break;       
         }
      }

 }

}

    if(isNumber&&isUpper&&islower&&length>=8 && isSpecialChar){

        return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: This looks more simpler!! Thanks !!